# How to detect anomalies in opencv (c++) if threshold is not good enought?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, anomaly-detection

I have grayscale images like this:

[image]
I want to detect anomalies on this kind of images. On the first image (upper-left) I want to detect three dots, on the second (upper-right) there is a small dot and a "Foggy area" (on the bottom-right), and on the last one, there is also a bit smaller dot somewhere in the middle of the image.

The normal static tresholding does't work ok for me, also Otsu's method is always the best choice. Is there any better, more robust or smarter way to detect anomalies like this? In Matlab I was using something like Frangi Filtering (eigenvalue filtering). Can anybody suggest good processing algorithm to solve anomaly detection on surfaces like this?

EDIT: Added another image with marked anomalies:

[image]

Using @Tapio 's tophat filtering and contrast adjustement.
Since @Tapio provide us with great idea how to increase contrast of anomalies on the surfaces like I asked at the begining, I provide all you guys with some of my results. I have and image like this:
[image]

Here is my code how I use tophat filtering and contrast adjustement:

```
kernel = getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(3, 3), Point(0, 0));
morphologyEx(inputImage, imgFiltered, MORPH_TOPHAT, kernel, Point(0, 0), 3);  
imgAdjusted = imgFiltered * 7.2;
```

The result is here:

[image]

**There is still question how to segment anomalies from the last image?? So if anybody have idea how to solve it, just take it! :) ??**

Comment: calculate the mean of the gray scale image. Pixels above a certain % of the mean can be declared as outliers

Comment: @JeruLuke: That's a "Intro to Pattern recognition" level answer, but the references to Otsu's method and Eigenvalue filtering tell me that we're not looking at that.

Comment: Can you provide more about whitch technique should I focus on and how to proceed in Pattern recognition? Should I be thinking also about some ''machine learning'' stuff here?

Comment: @skoda23: You _can_ of course throw a CNN at this, and given enough data that will work. Is it efficient? Not exactly. Do you need a lot of training data? Yes, at least in comparison to programming it directly. Is it trivial? No, you'll have quite a bit of work writing a useful error function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should take a look at bottom-hat filtering. It's defined as the difference of the original image and the morphological closing of the image and it makes small details such as the ones you are looking for flare out.

[image: first image pair]

[image: second image pair]

[image: third image pair]

I adjusted the contrast to make both images visible. The anomalies are much more pronounced when looking at the intensities and are much easier to segment out.

Let's take a look at the first image:

[image: segmentation accuracy needed]

The histogram values don't represent the reality due to scaling caused by the visualization tools I'm using. However the relative distances do. So now the thresholding range is much larger, the target changed from a window to a barn door.

Global thresholding ( intensity > 15 ) :

[image: After global thresholding]

Otsu's method worked poorly here. It segmented all the small details to the foreground.

After removing noise by morphological opening :

[image: After morphological opening]

I also assumed that the black spots are the anomalies you are interested in. By setting the threshold lower you include more of the surface details. For example the third image does not have any particularly interesting features to my eye, but that's for you to judge. Like m3h0w said, it's a good heuristic to know that if something is hard for your eye to judge it's probably impossible for the computer.

Comment: Thats some exelent work from you @Tapio. Can you provide me with some c++ code how did you solve tophat filtering and contrast adjustement for the first image? I tried tophat filtering and it works ok, but I cannot see the results as good  as you do.

Comment: @Tapio that's great work. Is that histogram visualization with threshold overlayed something you've created or is that some kind of prototyping tool?

Comment: @Tapio I added one of my results as you suggested to use tophat and adjustement. Can you provide us with your comment on that results and give us some additional advice how to improve them?

Answer (score 2):

@skoda23, I would try unsharp masking with fine tuned parameters for the blurring part, so that the high frequencies get emphasized and test it thoroughly so that no important information is lost in the process. Remember that it is usually not good idea to expect computer to do super-human work. If a human has doubts about where the anomalies are, computer will have to. Thus it is important to first preprocess the image, so that the anomalies are obvious for the human eye. Alternative for unsharp masking (or addition) might be CLAHE. But again: remember to fine tune it very carefully - it might bring out the texture of the board too much and interfere with your task.

Alternative approach to basic thresholding or Otsu's, would be `AdaptiveThreshold()` which might be a good idea since there is a difference in intensity values between different regions you want to find.

My second guess would be first using fixed value thresholding for the darkest dots and then trying Sobel, or Canny. There should exist an optimal neighberhood where texture of the board will not shine as much and anomalies will. You can also try bluring before edge detection (if you've detected the small defects with the thresholding).

Again: it is vital for the task to experiment a lot on every step of this approach, because fine tuning the parameters will be crucial for eventual success. I'd recommend making friends with [the trackbar](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/highgui/trackbar/trackbar.html), to speed up the process. Good luck!

Comment: I agree with all said. But I still cannot find the right parameters with trackbars. I am trying to solve the problem that the true world is "analog" like @MSalters said. I Added one additional image to my post. Please take a quick look. Can you recomend me, what should be the best filtering here. I'm currently trying with adaptive thresholding but cannot tune it up very well :/

Comment: @skoda23 it would be helpful for everybody if you'd provide us with images showing which of the anomalies you want to detect and which are normal and should be omitted

Comment: How about the texture that was visible on the 3 images you added before? Why is there no texture on the new image?

Comment: I am currently recording this images from my camera. I cleaned out the surface of the part a bit, so there is no foggy area anymore. But still you can se a lot of similar patterns on the new image. It is also true that ROI on the new image is much bigger that on the first images, so smaller detailes are not seen.

Comment: Well without the texture it's quite easy. Just compute the mean value and a basic threshold equal to some percentage of the mean value should be enough, since the board's intensity is very consistent on that last picture.

Comment: you suggested to calculate mean value of my ROI and then use that threshold should be in some range, for example [134 - 158] ? Can you provide me with some c++ code how can I do that? I tried to set up fixed level threshold using "threshold" function...

Comment: Yes. Detect the board. calculate mean value and base the threshold on that. Say if the mean is 130, your threshold would be 30% more, namely 170 (in reality anoher experimentally found value). By threshold equal to 170, I mean `cv2.threshold(img, 170, 255, 0)`. But since @Tapio got good results, you should definitely try implementing his idea.

Comment: Is there any example of c++ code for this approach? When I calculate mean value I don't get good results. Also I'm looking for automatic approach for anomaliy detection. In this example, I calculate mask of ROI using Otsu, this is working very good. But when it comes to choosing "anomaly threshold" automatically, there I have problems :/

Answer (score 2):

You're basically dealing with the unfortunate fact that reality is analog. A threshold is a method to turn an analog range into a discrete (binary) range. *Any* threshold will do that. So what exactly do you mean with a "good enough" threshold?

Let's park that thought for a second. I see lots of anomalies - sort of thin grey worms. Apparently, you ignore them. I'm applying a different threshold then you are. This may be reasonable, but you're applying domain knowledge that I don't have.

I suspect these grey worms will be throwing off your fixed value thresholding. That's not to say the idea of a fixed threshold is bad. You can use it to find *some* artifacts and exclude those. Somewhat darkish patches will be missed, but can be brought out by replacing  each pixel with the median value of its neighborhood, using a neighborhood size that's bigger than the width of those worms. In the dark patch, this does little, but it wipes out small local variations.

I don't pretend these two types of abnormalities are the only two, but that is really an application domain question and not about techniques. E.g. you don't appear to have ligthing artifacts (reflections), at least not in these 3 samples.