# How to segment anomalies on the glossy surface with opencv (c++)

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, anomaly-detection

I have an image of a glossy surface:
[image]

My goal is to detect anomalies on that image. The same image with marked anomalies I show you here:
[image]

As we can see from images above, anomalies have bad contrast (or at least not the best), and they are also changing from image to image by their shape, contrast, orientation...
I was trying to increase anomalies contrast by using tophat filtering. The result is here:
[image]
Now I anomalies are much more visible on the image, I want to segment them out from the image. The aim is to binarize image and use connectedComponents function to calculate areas, dimensions, positions of anomalies...

What kind of segmentation do you suggest? What would be the best way to binarize image? Should I even use tophat filtering to increase anomalies contrast or should I try to segment anomalies directly from first image?

Comment: You have asked a similar question before didn't you?? [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42480594/how-to-detect-anomalies-in-opencv-c-if-threshold-is-not-good-enought)

Comment: what exactly is your definition of "anomaly" here?

Comment: @slawekwin everything that is not totally clean glossy surface is anomaly. Soo... dust, fingerprint, scratches, foggy areas are example of some of possible anomalies.

Answer (score 1):

You can:

1. try several top hat filters of different sizes and parameters, to see which one highlights the anomalies best while suppressing the finger prints.

or

2. go directly to thresholding and adjust parameters there to make sure that none of the anomalies are lost in the process. Then use the features of connected components to extract the actual anomalies.

An increasingly popular approach is to train a deep neural network using lots of images of anomalies and then using the network to identify them.

Comment: I already tried changing parameters of  top hat filters and global tresholding. I also tried adaptiveThresholding(). Still it does not satisfy me in anomaly detection. (or maybe I'm doing something wrong). On the other side, I am very interested in "Neural Nets" idea, but I'm completely new in this. I know that there is a lot of literature on the internet but anyway, can you provide me with some additional information? Can I use neural nets approach in opencv (c++) ? Is it possible to get some code examples? I0m beginer in machine learning...

Comment: You need several images of the surface with no anomaly, and several others with anomalies. Then we can take the problem to the frequency domain, because anomalies are easier to detect their. Anomalies will be represented by high frequency values. If you remove the low frequency components (estimate threshold looking at your samples), you will have an image highlighting the defects. 
If you want to try neural networks for this purpose, http://machinelearningmastery.com has good tutorials. OpenCV does have machine learning support, but I am not aware of a good tutorial.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try to learn as musch ass possible. Then I will get images of healty and damaged surface ( how many samples are we talking about here? 10? 100? 1000? ). And another question: Must I use the whole image as one sample? Or can I record one image (like the first in post) and then cut this image to a lot of smaller images that represent anomalies and use them in learning time of neural nets?

Comment: Cutting the image to smaller images with anomalies is highly recommended, because that way different anomalies are not on the same image. You can do this to the images of the good surfaces, too. If you are trying frequency domain-based methods, 10 to 100 images will be enough to start with. For machine learrning, 1000s are the norm. But if you don't have that many, try with what you have.